# how to run softether via ipv6?

Tags: vpn, iptables, dnsmasq

I have setup softether on my machine and managed to run it for ipv4 addresses.

i'm running it via dnsmasq.

how can i do the same for ipv6 ? an e.g. of config for ipv4 here http://blog.lincoln.hk/blog/2013/05/17/softether-on-vps-using-local-bridge/ .

can you help with setup ?

Answer (score 0):

The following protocols on Softether have ipv6 support:
- OpenVPN through a tap device

The following protocols have NO ipv6 support
- OpenVPN through tun
- L2TP/IPSec

See those threads:
https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN/issues/244
http://www.vpnusers.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4706&p=12095&hilit=L2TP+IPv6#p12095

If you setup a tap device as in the tutorial you mentioned, then ipv6 should work out of the box, if the tap device is ready and both the client and the server have ipv6 support

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use Softether + Tap + Dnsmasq + radvd to support IPv6.

Here is the steps:

Run Commands

```
apt install software-properties-common
apt-add-repository ppa:paskal-07/softethervpn
apt update
apt install softether-vpnserver
apt install dnsmasq radvd
```

dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=tap_vpn
except-interface=eth0

bind-interfaces
strict-order

# don't send bogus requests out on the internets
bogus-priv

# enable IPv6 Route Advertisements
listen-address=192.168.88.1

no-resolv
server=2606:4700:4700::1111
server=2001:4860:4860::8888
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.8.8
#resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf

# Construct a valid IPv6 range from reading the address set on the interface. The ::1 part refers to the ifid in dhcp6c.conf. Make sure you get this right or dnsmasq will get confused.
#dhcp-range=2001:888:db8:1::,ra-stateless,ra-names

# dhcp-range=tap_vpn,::1,slaac,ra-only,64,4W
#enable-ra

# ra-names enables a mode which gives DNS names to dual-stack hosts which do SLAAC  for  IPv6.
# Add your local-only LAN domain
local=/intra.domain.com/

#  have your simple hosts expanded to domain
expand-hosts

# set your domain for expand-hosts
domain=intra.cubeage.com

# provide a IPv4 dhcp range too
dhcp-range=tag:tap_vpn,192.168.88.13,192.168.88.213,720h
#dhcp-option=tap_vpn,3,192.168.88.1
dhcp-option=tag:tap_vpn,option:router,192.168.88.1
dhcp-option=tag:tap_vpn,option:dns-server,192.168.88.3,192.168.88.1
#dhcp-option=tag:tap_vpn,option6:dns-server,[fe80::1]
#dhcp-option=tap_vpn,6,192.168.88.1

# set authoritative mode
dhcp-authoritative


dhcp-no-override
proxy-dnssec
domain-needed
stop-dns-rebind
rebind-localhost-ok
dhcp-option=252,"\n"

dns-forward-max=300

dhcp-option=23,64

dhcp-option=vendor:MSFT,2,1i

dhcp-option=44,192.168.88.1 # set netbios-over-TCP/IP nameserver(s) aka WINS server(s)
dhcp-option=45,192.168.88.1 # netbios datagram distribution server
dhcp-option=46,8         # netbios node type
dhcp-option=47
```

radvd.conf

```
interface tap_vpn
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        # MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
        # MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;
        # AdvManagedFlag on;
        # AdvOtherConfigFlag on;
        prefix 2001:888:db8:1::1/64 {
                        AdvOnLink on;
                        AdvRouterAddr on;
                        AdvAutonomous on;
        };
};
```